# Lorentzian fit warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated',

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a lorentzian curve with the following equation:
[Lorentzian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12yI5.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

# Fit a Lorentzian.
def duallorentz(x, x0, g, F,M) :
    return ( (F/M) /((x0**2 - x**2)**2 + (g*x)**2)**0.5) 
xdata = np.array([188.49, 191.63, 194.77, 196.66, 198.54, 200.43, 202.31 ,204.20,206.08,207.977,209.85])
ydata = np.array([0.0052, 0.0071, 0.0091, 0.0118,0.0152,0.225,0.228, 0.037, 0.017,0.012,0.009])

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'bo', label='experimental-data')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(duallorentz, xdata, ydata)
print(popt)

xFit = np.arange(0, 25)

plt.plot(xFit, duallorentz(xFit, *popt), 'r', label='fit params')

plt.xlabel('Frequency of the driven coupled oscillators.')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude of the driven coupled oscillators.')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Part II Data')

plt.show()
```

But it shows the message "warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated',". What's wrong here?

Comment: Probably starting guess. Check the `curve_fit` docu.

Comment: Are you sure about the formula you're using for the Lorentzian curve ? I have doubts about the `x` in `(g*x)**2)**0.5`

Comment: @Liris check the plotlabels, it suggest coupled, damped and driven oscillators; so it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Since your fit function depends on the ratio F/M, it cannot estimate the covariance of F and M separately.